# set product attribute without loading full product

Tags: product, attributes

```
Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($id, 'attribute', Mage::app()->getStore());
```

This can be used to fetch the product attribute by ID.  How can one set this value as well?

Answer (score 2):

For that you'll want the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Action` model.

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
    array(100, 200, 300),               // Product IDs to update
    array('my_attribute'=>'new value'), // Key/value pairs of attributes and their values
    1                                   // Store ID
);
```

Comment: I should note that this doesn't fire the usual `catalog_product_after_save` event, only `catalog_product_attribute_update_before` and `catalog_product_attribute_update_after` which might not reindex things or clear caches as you might expect, so use it carefully.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `saveAttribute` method of `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract` which `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract` extends:

```
$id = 905;
$attributeCode = 'name';

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->setStoreId(0);
$product->setId($id);
$product->setName('8GB Memory Card');

$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, $attributeCode);
```

Note that this will not work with attributes that have a static backend type like sku. Sku is actually a field in `catalog_product_entity` table.